# Internal web application is out of service when internet is down

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have an internal application to a LAN developed in Asp.net on IIS (Internet Information Services). When internet is absent the application is out of service, while in the LAN everything works.

Can you help me please?

Comment: do you use http:// hostname or http:// ip?

Comment: I asked, aspect response. @feiyun0112